# Always returning empty array of arrays, although it's showing successful transaction on Shasta Network

Tags: node.js, blockchain, solidity, tron, tronweb

I'm trying to get back all the `struct` type records from my `solidity contract` function please see the below `solidity contract` code snippet

```
struct Record {
    uint _id;
    string _countryCode;
    string _state;
    string _postal;
    string _location;
    string _userId;
    string _additionalDetails;
}
Record[] public records;

function getEntries() public view returns (Record[] memory) {
    return records;
}

function setRecord(
    string memory _countryCode,
    string memory _state,
    string memory _postal,
    string memory _location,
    string memory _userId,
    string memory _additionalDetails
) public onlyOwner {
    Record memory newStruct = Record({
        _id: _counter + 1,
        _countryCode: _countryCode,
        _state: _state,
        _postal: _postal,
        _location: _location,
        _userId: _userId,
        _additionalDetails: _additionalDetails
    });
    records.push(newStruct);
    _counter++;
}
```

I'm successfully able to add a new record using `tronweb` in `nodejs` below in my `NodeJs` code snippet

```
const walletAddress = "";
const privateKey = "";
const contractAddress = "";

tronweb.setAddress(walletAddress);
tronweb.setPrivateKey(privateKey);
const init = async () => {
    let contract = await tronweb.contract().at(contractAddress);
    const getRecords = async () => await contract.getEntries().call();
    const setRecord = async () => await contract.setRecord(

            "USA",
            "LA",
            "12345",
            "Street 1",
            "1324-12345-12456-45642",
            "Testing notes"

    ).send({
        "from": walletAddress
    });
    await setRecord();
    getRecords().then(result => {
        console.log(result); // getting empty array like [ [], [] ]
    });
};
init();
```

Here is the console image of my nodejs script results which is always returning an empty array of arrays

[image]

Here is the Shasta Network transaction details with status `CONFIRMED`

[image]

Is there anyone who can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ABI, any return value of a struct type will be interpreted as `tuple`. In your case, its type is `tuple[]`.

The library has no clue what's your `tuple` is, how long it is, what's the type.

You should parse the return data by hand.

```js
{
  "constant_result": [
    "000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000040000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000080000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000030000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000140000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000018000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001c00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003555341000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000024c4100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000053132333435000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000853747265657420310000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000016313332342d31323334352d31323435362d343536343200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000d54657374696e67206e6f74657300000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000140000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000018000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001c00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003555341000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000024c4100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000053132333435000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000853747265657420310000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000016313332342d31323334352d31323435362d343536343200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000d54657374696e67206e6f74657300000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000300000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000140000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000018000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001c00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003555341000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000024c4100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000053132333435000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000853747265657420310000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000016313332342d31323334352d31323435362d343536343200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001254657374696e672077697468204a616d65730000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000140000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000018000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001c00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003555341000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000024c4100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000053132333435000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000853747265657420310000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000016313332342d31323334352d31323435362d343536343200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001e54657374696e672077697468204a616d6573206e65772076657273696f6e0000"
  ],
  "result": {
    "code": "SUCCESS",
    "message": "",
    "result": true
  }
}
```

To parse the constant_result:

- align it by a 64-char boundary (256bits)
- normally the values are offsets or lengths
- for the detail, you should refer to ETH ABI doc

```
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020  offset of first parm
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000080  
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000300
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000580
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000800
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001  #first
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000140
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000180
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001c0
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001  
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000240
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003  a string with 3 chars
5553410000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000  "USA"
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002  a string with 2 chars
4c41000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000  "LA"
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005  
3132333435000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000  '12345'
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008
5374726565742031000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000  'Street 1'
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000016
313332342d31323334352d31323435362d343536343200000000000000000000  '1324-12345-12456-45642'
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000d
54657374696e67206e6f74657300000000000000000000000000000000000000  'Testing notes'
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002  #second
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000140
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000180
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001c0
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000240
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003
5553410000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002
4c41000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005
3132333435000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008
5374726565742031000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000016
313332342d31323334352d31323435362d343536343200000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000d
54657374696e67206e6f74657300000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003  #third
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000140
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000180
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001c0
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000240
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003
5553410000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002
4c41000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005
3132333435000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008
5374726565742031000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000016
313332342d31323334352d31323435362d343536343200000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000012
54657374696e672077697468204a616d65730000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004   #fourth
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000140
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000180
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001c0
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000240
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003
5553410000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002
4c41000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005
3132333435000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008
5374726565742031000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000016
313332342d31323334352d31323435362d343536343200000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001e
54657374696e672077697468204a616d6573206e65772076657273696f6e0000
```

Comment: You should use multiple return values instead of a `struct[]`. Like `returns (string[], string[], ...)`